# Usb wireless card TP-LINK WN822n

Tags: usb

I just bought this usb, and for the past three days. I have been trying to connect it. Without any success so far. My laptop can t even detect it, try it on virtualbox with kali. Nothing, can someone give me a guideline on what to do. Kind new to Ubuntu and have a small knowledge on Linux in general

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu as a Host (physical device) and Kali as a guest (Virtual Machine).

Assuming "yes", you have to add your user to vboxusers group.
To do that, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME vboxusers
```

Then you will need to close your session or reboot the computer and try again.

For more information, take a look to this article: [Set up USB for VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB)

Comment: Yes my OS is Ubuntu and use kali as my virtual machine

Comment: I have try that, I click on device and chose usb in virtualbox, it say no usb connected. Im just puzzle at the moment.

Comment: Open a terminal and run: `lsusb'  and paste the output.
Remember to close your Ubuntu session in your host machine, login and then try again. Changes in groups requires logout & login to take effect. Rebooting your host machine works too.

Comment: I will try this and hopefully something positive will come up, do you mind to show me a screen shot from an output. Thanks

Comment: Could you include the solution into your answer instead of simply linking to another website?

Comment: @Weboide Thank you for the advice. I've edited the answer to include the solution.